# Add column to a table in SQL Server database and make the default value with a cases

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I need to add a column `IsDeleted` to table `Major` with default value will be :
True when the MajorName like `'%Engineering%'` and false in the others which not have a word Engineering

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add it as as [computed column](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188300.aspx) (AKA virtual column)

```
alter table Major add IsDeleted as 
    cast (case when MajorName like '%Engineering%' then 1 else 0 end as bit)
```

---

Demo

```
create table Major (MajorName varchar (100))

alter table Major add IsDeleted as 
    cast (case when MajorName like '%Engineering%' then 1 else 0 end as bit)

insert into Major (MajorName) values 
    ('This is the Engineering department'),('Hello world')

select * from Major
```

---

```
+------------------------------------+-----------+
| MajorName                          | IsDeleted |
+------------------------------------+-----------+
| This is the Engineering department | 1         |
+------------------------------------+-----------+
| Hello world                        | 0         |
+------------------------------------+-----------+
```

Comment: Need to set the datatype equal bit and the default value equal to the return case value

Comment: it's work correctly but the datatype field get empty field

Comment: What do you mean? where?

Comment: its like a virtual column i need the column has a datatype and also can change the value anytime

Comment: So this in not the solution you are looking for.

Comment: yes i need a really column has a datatype and default value, instead of the default value equal false , will be true where like

Comment: `UPDATE [Major]
set isdeleted=  1
where name like '%Engineering%'`

Answer (score 0):

To add column to your table :

```
ALTER TABLE yourtable ADD IsDeleted bit ;
```

To check MajorName  and set IsDeleted to1 or 0 Use `Trigger`